# I need to add multiple printers to multiple print servers with Powershell and a single .csv file

Tags: powershell, printing, server, import-csv

I have a script that will run against an Excel file for a list of printers as well as the the listed print server.

The issue I cant figure out is how to add multiple printers to multiple print servers without having an Excel sheet with 200 lines.

I would like to have the print servers listed in the Powershell script and have the `foreach` command go through each server listed dynamically.

Here is the code I have so far. I am trying to get the `$server` to be able to have a list of servers and change the part in the function to the next server on the list.
I attached an example of what the .csv formatting looks like. [example of the formatting of the .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYbYp.jpg) Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

```
function CreatePrinter {
    $server = $args[0]
    $print = ([WMICLASS]"\\$server\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_Printer").createInstance() 
    $print.drivername = $args[1]
    $print.PortName = $args[2]
    $print.Shared = $false
    $print.Sharename = $args[3]
    $print.Location = $args[4]
    $print.Comment = $args[5]
    $print.DeviceID = $args[6]
    $print.Put() 
}

function CreatePrinterPort {
    $server =  $args[0] 
    $port = ([WMICLASS]"\\$server\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort").createInstance()
    $port.Name= $args[1]
    $port.SNMPEnabled=$false 
    $port.Protocol=1 
    $port.HostAddress= $args[2]
    $port.Put() 
}

$printers = Import-Csv C:\test\NewPrinters.csv

foreach ($printer in $printers) {
    CreatePrinterPort $printer.Printserver $printer.Portname $printer.IPAddress
    CreatePrinter $printer.Printserver $printer.Driver $printer.Portname 
    $printer.Sharename $printer.Location $printer.Comment $printer.Printername
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel when you can use the existing commands for printer management.

`Add-PrinterPort` and `Add-Printer` will what you want:

```
foreach ($printer in $printers) {
    Add-PrinterPort -ComputerName $printer.Printserver -Name $printer.Portname -PrinterHostAddress $printer.IPAddress
    Add-Printer -ComputerName $printer.Printserver -Name $printer.Printername -DriverName $printer.Driver -Shared -ShareName $printer.Sharename -PortName $printer.Portname -Comment $printer.Comment -Location $printer.Location
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

For multiple servers:

```
$servers = "printserver01","printserver02","printserver03"

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    foreach ($printer in $printers) {
        Add-PrinterPort -ComputerName $server -Name $printer.Portname -PrinterHostAddress $printer.IPAddress
        Add-Printer -ComputerName $server -Name $printer.Printername -DriverName $printer.Driver -Shared -ShareName $printer.Sharename -PortName $printer.Portname -Comment $printer.Comment -Location $printer.Location
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I be able to run this against a list of servers and list of printers?

Comment: It can already do that, just update your CSV accordingly... add your servers under `Printserver` column and printers as per other columns, if you need same printer on multiple servers just duplicate the row and change `Printserver` to next server name.

Comment: That's how my current script works. Your code is much simpler and nicer looking.  I was trying to avoid having a large excel sheet. I have to add about 100 printers across 8 print servers. So the excel sheet would be 800 lines long hahaha. I was trying to have it where it could have a list of servers and then a the list of 100 printers with the printer attributes to avoid 800 lines on an excel sheet.

Comment: Dang... I am on a windows 7 computer and the module for PrintManagement can't be loaded on a windows 7 computer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add the printers to multiple servers without duplicate entries. The PrintManagement module was introduced with Windows 8 and Server 2012 (and newer) if you've got a machine with either of those on you're good, if not you can replace the two commands with yours and the two `foreach` loops will function the same.

Comment: The script works perfect... But when I run it, it will only install the printer on the machine I am running the script from even though I specify different servers.

Comment: Sorry, realised I'd made a mistake in my update, need to replace `$printer.Printserver` with `$server` so it uses `$servers` array!

Comment: You sir are my Hero. You seriously saved me so much time and so many lines of unnecessary code. I would buy you a beer if I could. Seriously I cant thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Also no need to say Sorry... You took the time out of your day to answer a question for some random dude. This is what my final script looks like and it works flawlessly on Windows Server 2012.

```
foreach ($server in @("Printserver1","Printserver2","Printserver3")) {
   foreach ($printer in @(Import-Csv C:\PrinterList.csv)) {
      Add-PrinterPort -ComputerName $server -Name $printer.IPAddress -PrinterHostAddress $printer.IPAddress
      Add-Printer -ComputerName $server -Name $printer.Printername -DriverName $printer.Driver -PortName $printer.IPAddress -Comment $printer.Comment -Location $printer.Location
   }
}
```

-Nick-